# Difference between type and lifetime qualifiers

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

In Objective-C or any other language that applies?

I guess what I'm really asking is, is the `__weak` and `const` the same in terms of classification? Can I interchange the terms type and lifetime qualifiers when I'm talking about `__weak`, `const`, etc?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C, a type qualifier attaches a quality (an attribute, a property) to a given type. There are three type qualifiers: `const` (readonly, no writes), `volatile` (no cache) and `restrict` (no alias).

Automatic reference counting (for Objective-C) adds four new type qualifiers: `__autoreleasing`, `__strong`, `__unsafe_unretained` and `__weak`. Because of the nature of ARC — namely, automating memory management — these four type qualifiers attach attributes related to ownership.

> I guess what I'm really asking is, is the `__weak` and `const` the same in terms of classification?

They’re both type qualifiers but only `__weak` is an ownership qualifier.

> Can I interchange the terms type and lifetime qualifiers when I'm talking about `__weak`, `const`, etc?

No, they’re not interchangeable. All qualifiers listed above are type qualifiers but only the four qualifiers introduced by ARC are *also* ownership qualifiers.

Note that [the LLVM project](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) uses the denomination **ownership qualifiers** whereas [Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html) seem to be using **lifetime qualifiers** instead.

Answer (score 0):

const specifies that object cannot be changed over its life cycle.

__weak implies that the object reference doesn't increment the reference count, when you are using ARC this is useful for objects you either don't own or don't want to increase reference count such as a circular reference count. strong would be the default and implies the reference count changes.

Comment: Note that the question isn’t about the difference between `__weak` and `const`. Instead, it’s about the terms _type qualifier_ and _ownership qualifier._